# Why not text element showing up?

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Transformations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="transformations.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
           Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ullam maxime ad aspernatur quos minus quam repellendus ea voluptatibus doloremque magni laborum ipsa dolores praesentium saepe, cum reiciendis consectetur voluptates.
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I ran this HTML code & found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUoZY.png) error

I used live server as extension.

Comment: I would assume your URL is either incorrectly encoded or the file does not exist under that path

Comment: Other HTML codes are running perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you add `[` before `<html>` and `][1]` after `</html>`

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ullam maxime ad aspernatur quos minus quam repellendus ea voluptatibus doloremque magni laborum ipsa dolores praesentium saepe, cum reiciendis consectetur voluptates.
</div>
```

Comment: Please run it now. That was a typing mistake while posting it here. Sorry.

Comment: you didn't remove `[` still

Comment: I think the additonal characters are coming from an incorrect formatted question and are not part of the actual code

Comment: Found an extra "[" character. But still not running